# not able to get user info

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-plus, google-people-api, userinfo

bellow is my node js script to get google user details using accessToken

```
 var accessToken = req.body.accessToken;
            console.log(accessToken)


            var google = require('googleapis');
            //google api
            var plus = google.plus('v1');
            var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

            var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
                config.google.clientID,
                config.google.clientSecret,
                config.google.redirect_uri
            );
            oauth2Client.setCredentials({access_token: accessToken});
            plus.people.get({
                userId: 'me',
                auth: oauth2Client
            }, function (err, response) {
                // handle err and response
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                } else {
                    console.log(response);
                    resolve(response)
                }
            });
```

need to get google login user details using accessToken. what is wrong in code?

Comment: Whats the error?  What scopes did you send with authentication? Why are you going though google plus?

Comment: @DaImTo i get the access token from mobile app after login with google. i need to get details of user who loggedIn by generated access token. and check from database.

Comment: What kind of mobile app?  your question is taged node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is the user in question has not created a google+ profile.  Here are a few more options.

I am not sure what information you are trying to get but the best way to get user info is to authecate a user using the profile scope then request the data directly of the user info endpoint

Request

```
GET /userinfo/v2/me HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer uzG4XqnvucBFk3jylgxnbtNhoOt2wCc3QvUcjk7PZhJ5m6G7ibtlBwbAQntJjJtLsxZfoDjhbASpzLmcFnlZ9o4qoMd2fCV2eRb4O5XrKRAXC
```

Response

```
{
  "family_name": "Lawton", 
  "name": "Linda Lawton", 
  "picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAl1I/UcwPajZOuN4/photo.jpg", 
  "locale": "en", 
  "gender": "female", 
  "link": "https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton", 
  "given_name": "Linda", 
  "id": "117200475532672775346"
}
```

You can also go though the google people api using the same profile scope

```
GET /v1/people/me HTTP/1.1
Host: people.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer NuzG4XqnvucBFk3jylgxnbtNhoOt2wCc3QvUcjk7PZhJ5m6G7ibtlBwbAQntJjJtLsxZfoDjhbASpzLmcFnlZ9o4qoMd2fCV2eRb4O5XrKRAXC
```

But this endpoint reads from Google+ so if the user has not filled anything out on their Google+ profile you wont see much data here.

Comment: To clarify the Google People API which is different than the G+ People API, will work with non G+ users. It will return only public data by default. But you can get additional private data by requesting scopes such as as the `profile` scope. See [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing#profile-scopes) for other scopes you can request to get additional private data. The Google People API should return all of the data that the userinfo endpoint returns and more.

Comment: Google people API is actually linked to Google contacts and is not associated with Google plus however I suspect that it reads its initial data from Google plus when they initialize this new API a few years ago as the data apears the same but I haven't asked Google for verification of this theory its just a guess

Comment: @asmos I think if you read my answer it mentions using the profile scope

Comment: @DalmTo Right I saw that you mentioned the profile scope. The last line of your post "But this endpoint reads from Google+ so if the user has not filled anything out on their Google+ profile you wont see much data here." seems to imply that People API only reads from Google+.

I'm clarifying that Google People API works with non G+ users and will read the same data that the userinfo endpoint reads and more (G+ profile, contacts, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **request** module to get the user detail on your node server.

---

But Before requesting the user data, make sure you have authorized the API by giving it the desired scope. In your case, you need to give `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` in the scope.

---

When you receive your accessToken, use that token to call this google api

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
```

```js
const request = require('request');
// use any api you want to call.
request({
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${YourAccessToken}`,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
}, function(err, response, _user) {
  console.log('User Data', _user);
})
```

---

I hope this will solve your problem. If still there is some problem, you can test your Google APIs on [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)